# NullPointerException onDestory

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

When the app starts and I try to immediately rotate the screen It gives me this error:

```
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        appbars.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    }
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.animate()' on a null object
 reference
```

Comment: AppBarLayout might not be initialized (findViewById)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this check your `appbars` is null or not like this

```
 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
       if(appbars!=null) {
       appbars.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }
```

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       if(appbars!=null){  // use this 
     appbars.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());   

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your appbars was destroyed and no more exist. Also you need to move stop work in onPause() for better performance.

Activity lifecycle :

[image]

Comment: As fellow members suggested: problem was `onDestroy` triggered before the `AppBarLayout` loaded thus I got the null pointer error

Comment: I was tell you about bad practice in your code. If you want to get answer how avoid this you had to many examples below. GL and HF

Comment: If i don't use `onDestory` I have to implement this code in other tabs as well. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

try with this..

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(appbars!=null) {
       appbars.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..